# Why is the old mysql password function considered insecure

Tags: mysql, security, passwords

I know that the old mysql password function (pre-4.1) is considered insecure, but I'm not sure why. What are the specific reasons that it's considered insecure?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [MySQL docs on password hashing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html):

> The password hashing mechanism was updated in MySQL 4.1 to provide
>   better security and to reduce the risk of passwords being intercepted.

I'm not sure if it means anything additional by "reduce the risk of passwords being intercepted" or if it just means they're harder to crack, but the major difference is the size of the resulting hash.

Prior to 4.1, the hash size was 16 bytes.
As of 4.1+, the hash size is 41 bytes (`*` + 40 bytes).

A 16-byte hash is pretty small and easy to find collisions for, relative to larger hash functions. MD5 is generally considered to be of insufficient strength, and it yields twice that -- 32 bytes. Comparably, 16 bytes is basically pathetic. For comparison:

```
pre-4.1 MySQL PASSWORD:  16 bytes  
                   MD5:  32 bytes
                 SHA 1:  40 bytes
   4.1+ MySQL PASSWORD:  41 bytes (40 bytes, prepended with an asterisk)
               SHA-256:  64 bytes
               SHA-512: 128 bytes
```

The new password hashing scheme is on par with SHA-1, which is slightly better than MD5 but still not of sufficient strength to be recommended for passwords.

Answer (score 1):

According to: [Old MySQL password cracking](http://www.emase.co.uk/old-mysql-passwords-insecure-and-easy-to-crack/)

> Using the old password format a 16 byte hash is created such as:
>
> 6f8c114b58f2ce9e
>
> For the same password the MySQL4.1 hash is 41 bytes long:
>
> *6C8989366EAF75BB670AD8EA7A7FC1176A95CEF4
>
> On the surface it might seem that this extra level of security granted
>   by using the new passwords might not be significant. However, source
>   code has been released under the creative common license which allows
>   very quick cracking of old MySQL password.
>
> The password ‘a@4~1b’ has a hash of 2c28061c5bda971d.
>
> Using the cracking program mentioned above, this password can be
>   cracked in under 1 second on a 2 year old laptop.
>
> By using a SQL injection attack it might be possible for a user
>   without permission to view your my.cnf file. Entering this in a search
>   box could render the contents of the file in the browser if the second
>   param in the select statement was being shown on the screen and not
>   escaped correctly:
>
> something’ UNION ALL SELECT 1,(SELECT
>   LOAD_FILE(‘/etc/my.cnf’)),3,4,5,password FROM user ORDER BY ’7

If an unauthorised user is able to intercept your hashed passwords it is very easy to brute force them and obtain the plain text passwords. Complex passwords are still hard to crack, but an 8 character password will take very little time.

Since the changes to the length of the MySQL password hash, it is much harder to brute force the hashes.

Comment: The link is dead. I'm looking for that cracking utility.